# Entering Germany With a Georgian visa

Tags: visas

I'm an African and have been granted a Georgian visa, can I enter Germany with that visa ? Is my visa recognized as Schengen?

Comment: Georgian or German?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: @gerrit there is no African country on the Schengen visa-free list.

Answer (score 9):

No. Georgia is not one of the Schengen countries.

There are several countries, including Georgia, that provide an exemption from the visa requirement for travelers who hold visas from certain third countries.  Details of Georgia's program can be found here, under paragraph 5, which lists 50 countries whose visas qualify: [Other conditions for Georgian visa exemption](https://www.geoconsul.gov.ge/HtmlPage/Html/View?id=26&lang=Eng).

These arrangements are not reciprocal, however; they are unilateral.  Georgia did not enact such a policy on the condition that Germany enact a similar policy; rather, the policy serves as a convenience to Georgia.  The policy allows Georgia to reduce the number of visa applications it must handle.  It is also convenient for frequent travelers who want to visit Georgia, since it reduces the number of visas they must apply for.  This is an additional benefit for Georgia because it encourages tourism and business travel.

Georgia has presumably decided that these benefits are justified because their cost is low.  In other words, they can basically trust that Germany only grants visas to people who are also acceptable to the Georgian government.

Germany, on the other hand, and indeed the Schengen area, have little justification for ceding this kind of control to an non-member country.  As a richer and larger country, and a more popular destination for immigrants, Germany has more resources to devote to evaluating visa applications and more at stake in decisions about whom to let in.

The Wikipedia article lists the Schengen countries:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area

The current members are:

- Austria
- Belgium
- Czech Republic
- Denmark
- Estonia
- Finland
- France
- Germany
- Greece
- Hungary
- Iceland
- Italy
- Latvia
- Liechtenstein
- Lithuania
- Luxembourg
- Malta
- Netherlands
- Norway
- Poland
- Portugal
- Slovakia
- Slovenia
- Spain
- Sweden
- Switzerland

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that the reason one may think that a Georgian visa grants access to Germany, is that Georgia admits persons with a Schengen visa (but not a Georgian visa) under certain circumstances

Comment: @CMaster very good point.  I've added a little discussion of that.